# Htaccess file redirect not working any more switched https virtual host

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, bots

I have recently switched my site over to https using a virtual host, the bots dont seem to re-directing to the snapshot page now, the site when i got direct the url redirects to https, but my htaccess does not seem to be aware of the re-direct stup...

The re-direct to the snapshot was working preivously before the https..

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} https://upfrontbeats\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /snapshots/index.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} facebookexternalhit/1.1|Twitterbot/1.0 [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} https://upfrontbeats\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /snapshots/index.html [L,R=301]
```

This is bottom half still works fine its just the root url

```
######################################THIS NEEDS TO GO ON TOP TO STOP RE DIRECT LOOP AS IT HITS SNAP SHOT DIRECTORY
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]  
################################

# RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} upfrontbeats\.com [NC]
# RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_=(.*)$ 
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /snapshots/index.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} facebookexternalhit/1.1|Twitterbot/1.0 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_=(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /snapshots/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /snapshots/%1? [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: So what URL is not working now?

Comment: the main root url.. https://upfrontbeats\.com does not seem to get redirected to the snapshot anymore...

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} https://upfrontbeats\.com [NC]` is incorrect as you can only match domain name not scheme using `HTTP_HOST`

Comment: My knowledge is limited on this kind of stuff.. would be great if you could point in the right direction... thanks

Comment: the top part does not work at all either for Googlebot or social bots... the bottom half does.. I need of way of detecing the root url only and then redirect to the snapshot folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only match domain name not scheme using `HTTP_HOST` variable.

Keep your first redirect rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot|facebookexternalhit|Twitterbot [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} upfrontbeats\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /snapshots/index.html [L,R=301]
```